Free variable restrictions on Separation
I have been looking through the axioms of CZF and IZF article on SEP: https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/set-theory-constructive/axioms-CZF-IZF.html#:~:text=axioms%20of%20czf%20and%20izf.
In reading through it, something occurred to me that I hadn’t thought of before. Take the axiom schema of Separation:
$∀a∃x∀y(y∈x↔(y∈a∧ϕ(y)))$, where $x$ is not free in $ϕ(y)$.
I have no intuition for why $x$ must not be free in $\phi(y)$, but various sources that I’ve checked ensure that this is the correct version. I also notice that Replacement and Collection have similar restrictions.
What is going on here? What kind of unsound inferences can be made without the restriction?

Beyond avoiding paradoxes, the point of the restriction is that without it the axiom does not make any sense: $\phi$ is a predicate on the elements of $a$, why would it involve its own extension? First-order logic is tedious in this way: we are forced to constantly check that our formulas are well-scoped. Type theory avoids these kinds of issues by being explicit about contexts.

The point of the axiom is just to ensure the existence of a set consisting of the elements of $a$ that satisfy a well-defined predicate $\phi$. If $\phi$ were allowed to mention the set whose existence is being asserted, then the axiom would be doing something else, asserting the existence of sets defined by properties beyond the intended simple descriptions and opening the door to forms of self-reference or impredicativity that lead to paradoxes that ZF is carefully designed to avoid.

This is to avoid Russell's Paradox (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox). Assume the comprehension scheme included formulas in which $x$ was free, then in particular taking the instance of comprehension with $\phi(y,x)=\neg(y\in x)$ would imply:
\begin{equation*}
\forall a\, \exists x\,\forall y \;(y\in x\leftrightarrow (y\in a\wedge \neg(y\in x)))
\end{equation*}
which implies a contradiction. For similar reasons the schemes of replacement and collection have to be restricted to formulas in which $x$ is not free.
